# Character does not bind with Ckeditor bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

i am using a plugin to add new language characters for Ckeditor, i have debug this plugin it is changing English to my desired language character but does not showing me this new character in Editor.
One thing more

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'plugin_Name',
   {
      init : function( editor )
      {
          editor.on( 'contentDom', function( e ) {
            var doc = editor.document.$;
            if ( CKEDITOR.env.ie ) {        // If Internet Explorer.
               doc.attachEvent("onkeydown", DenIE_OnKeyDown ) ;
               doc.attachEvent("onkeypress", DenIE_OnKeyPress ) ;
            } else {                // If Gecko.
               doc.addEventListener( 'keydown', DenGecko_OnKeyDown, true ) ;
               doc.addEventListener( 'keypress', DenGecko_OnKeyPress, true ) ;
            }
         });

      } //Init
   } );
```

I have console doc variable this returns

```
Object { $: HTMLDocument → blank }
```